# Reproducing this chi-square probability from published work

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-distribution, sphericity

So i'm working on a Greenhouse-Geisser correction and i found this "John, Nagao & Sugiura’s test for sphericity" in this publication (https://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/abdi-GreenhouseGeisser2010-pretty.pdf).

[image]

Could it be that they calculated the value of the chi square distribution wrong? After Equation 20 they calculate the probability p=0.004, but when i use scipy, i get p=0.0004. So i'm confused if i did not understand the process right or if there is an error(my guess).

Comment: It's a typographical error: they omitted a "0" in the expression of the p-value.

Comment: Exactly as i thought. Thanks for the second opinion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the numbers they give produce a p-value of `0.000402`. They probably made a typo in their publication.

The [site](https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/chidistribution.aspx) I used to compute the p-value.